# How to implement "Item Limit" for Summary Link Webpart?

Tags: web-part

I would like to know how it is possible to do Item Limit (similar to Content Query Web Parts) for Summary Link Web Parts? Basically I want to limit the number of links they have there to a certain number, so it won't mess up with the styling of the page when users input too many items.

I've tried modifying the .WEBPART and inserting a 5, from which I got from a CQWP webpart file. However, it seems SharePoint doesn't implement this as it seems to automatically remove the snippet when I insert it to the page.

Is there a way to implement Item Limit functionality for Summary Links Web Part? OOTB would be better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to customize Summary Link web part

[SummaryLinkWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.summarylinkwebpart%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is XSL based web part. The following files:

- SummaryLinkMain.xsl
- ItemStyle.xsl
- HeaderStyle.xsl

define the rendering of Summary Link web part.

In order to specify the rows limit, follow the steps below:

1) Export web part and specify the [ParameterBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.parameterbindings.aspx) web part property:

```
<ParameterBindings>
   <ParameterBinding Name="RowsLimit" DefaultValue="2" />
</ParameterBindings>
```

where `ParameterBinding` `RowsLimit` corresponds to the maximum number of rows that should be rendered (in this case 2 rows should be displayed)

2) Open `SummaryLinkMain.xsl` (located under `Style Library > XSL Style Sheets`), declare parameter `<xsl:param name="RowsLimit" />` and 
replace

```
<xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$RowCount" />
```

with

```
<xsl:with-param name="LastRow" select="$RowsLimit" />
```

in `OuterTemplate` template

3) Upload web part and add it into the page

> Note: it is not recommended to modify system files like
>   `SummaryLinkMain.xsl`, so consider to create a separate file